# MIPS: find the first occurrence of the character in a string.(get some errors)

Tags: mips

I want to call the *strchr* function to find the first occurrence of the character in a string. But I get many difficulties. I don't know how to return a value from a procedure and I also don't understand when i should use 'sw' and 'lw'. I have seen many examples but I am still not clear. Could someone can help me?

this is the algorithm:

```
int strchr(char needle, char[] hay stack){
    for(int i = 0; haystack[i] != NUL; i++)
       if(haystack[i] == needle)
           return i;
    return i; 
}

void main(void){
     int offset;
     char haystack[256];
     char needle[2]
     offset = strchr(neesle[0], haystack);
     if(offset >= 0)
          printf("found at offset: %d", offset);
     else
          printf("not found")
    }
```

> this is my code, I don't know where the problem is.

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Please enter something: "
prompt2: .asciiz "Please enter one character: "
result2: .asciiz "\nnot found"
result: .asciiz "\nfound at offset: %d\n"
haystack: .space 256
needle: .space 2
.text
.globl main

main:
      li $v0, 4          #printf prompt
      la $a0, prompt
      syscall

      li $v0, 8          #read haystack
      la $a0, haystack   
      li $a1, 256
      syscall

      li $v0, 4          #printf prompt2
      la $a0, prompt2
      syscall

      li $v0, 8          #read needle
      la $a0, needle
      li $a1, 2
      syscall

      la $a0, haystack
      la $a1, needle
      jal strchr

      move $a0, $v0
      slt $t0, $a0, $zero
      bne $t0, $zero, result
      li $v0, 4
      la $a0, result2
      syscall
      j exit


exit:
      li $v0, 10
      syscall

strchr:addi $sp, $sp, -1032
       sw $s0, 0($sp)
       move $s0, $zero     # i=0
       add $t0,$zero,$a0
       add $t1,$zero,$a1
    L1:add $t2, $t0, $s0   # reg $t2 = haystack [i]
       lb $t3, 0($t2)      # reg $t3 = haystack[i]
       lb $t4, 0($t1)
       beq $t2, $zero, end # if haystack[i] == NUL, it is finished.

       bne $t2, $a1, pro
       move $v0, $s0     #return i 
       addi $s0, $s0, 1    
       j L1

pro:   
     li $v0, -1       #return -1

end: lw $s0, 0($sp)
     addi $sp, $sp,1032
     jr $ra
```